# JavaScript with multiple popups

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am trying to open a new pop up for my application, and each popup has a window name. Suppose if the user closes the popup he can open the popup with same name, else the existing pop up should be displayed.

I wrote the below code to do that, but this is not opening a popup if the user closes it else its opening a new popup. Please suggest how can go with this.

```
d='javascript:if(document.getElementsByTagName("*").length>0&&document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML!=""&&!confirm("You are about to navigate to home page Do you want to do that ? "))
{opener.display2WindowHelp();}
else
{window.location.replace("${pageContext.request.scheme}://${pageContext.request.serverName}:${pageContext.request.serverPort}${pageContext.request.contextPath}'+d+'");
}';
b= window.open(d,"_spor_window_"+a+window.location.hostname.replace(/\./g,""),"menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,height="+screen.availHeight+",width="+screen.availWidth+",left=0,top=0,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no");
```

Comment: Can you un-obfuscate the code and make it readable?  Also, are all these pop-ups necessary?  Why not something like the jQuery UI dialog instead?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to open any popups, there are likely better ways to meet your requirements. If you are opening several popups, then your design needs a thorough review (consider your workflow and whether a tabbed interface is a better option).

The usual strategy is to save a reference to each window, then check if it's still open and available for re-use later, e.g.

```
var popWin;

function openWindow(url) {
  var windowName = '...';
  var features = '...';

  if (!popWin || popWin.closed) {
    popWin = window.open(url, windowName, features);

  } else {
    popWin.location.href = url;
  }
}
```

If you want to have multiple windows open, then you will need a strategy for tracking which one you want to load a particular resource into.

You may find the [HTML5 window](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#apis-for-creating-and-navigating-browsing-contexts-by-name) (creating and navigating contexts by name) and [MDN window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open) documentation useful.

Comment: i also need to check win with same name is open or not ..so i guess i cant use this ..

Comment: @T Nina - how about keeping an array of all your windows and loop through the array looking for a match on the name?

Comment: @T Nina - what I posted isn't meant to be a cut 'n paste solution, it's a hint on how to go about it. As nnnnnn says, you'll need to keep references to the windows you've opened in an array or object and cycle through them to see if one with a particular name is already open or not. If so, reuse it. If not, open a new one and add it to the array or object (i.e. "…a strategy for tracking which one you want to load a particular resource into").